# How to get form title (form text) by form name - winform C#

Tags: c#, winforms, forms, devexpress

I have a code to get all form NAME on my project.

```
try
{
    Assembly assemblies = Assembly.Load("ProjectMyNameSpace");
    Type[] types = assemblies.GetTypes();
    foreach (Type t in types)
    {
        if (t.BaseType == typeof(XtraForm) | t.BaseType == typeof(XtraUserControl))
        {   
            checklistBox.Items.Add(t.Name);
            //<= t.Name like "frm_Login, frm_UserInfo...etc"
        }
    }
 }
 catch
 {
 }
```

But now, i want get Form.Text by form name.
How i can do it?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WwNdY.png]

Comment: You really want to get a fast answer? Then ask a clear understandable question!

Comment: @ChristianSt.Where unclear understandable?

Comment: Is `XtraUserControl` a form type?

Comment: @AlexJolig but it still have TITLE like form type.

Comment: Your question is actually unclear. You can't get the `Text` property value without creating a new instance of this form. The code snippet you provided does not explain when an how these instances will be created.

Comment: @DmitryG
So how i can get Form.Text of a form, when i know its name?

Comment: @GinCanhViet If you have some list of forms(e.g. [Application.OpenedForms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.openforms(v=vs.110).aspx))you can iterate these forms and return the `Text` property value when name or type of current instance match the conditions.

Comment: @DmitryG i have tried it.
 Application.OpenedForms(frmName).Text
Its not work!

Comment: Ok, i will convert my comments into answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't get the `Text` property value without creating a new instance of this form. The code snippet you provided does not explain when an how these instances will be created.

If you have some list of forms(e.g. [Application.OpenForms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.openforms(v=vs.110).aspx))you can iterate these forms and return the Text property value when name or type of current instance match the conditions:

```
Form f = Application.OpenForms["formName"];
if (f != null) {
  // do something with f.Text;
}
```

Comment: Application.OpenForms, have no  Application.OpenedForms.

Comment: It's work, but not with all form. Still have some problem! Thank you so much!

Comment: It's only work with form opened! :(

Comment: @GinCanhViet Thanks, i've corrected my answer with replacement `OpenedForms -> OpenForms`. Regarding the issue with all forms - as i've already mentioned **you should get the instance of form (instance but not a type) before getting it's text**.

Comment: Do you have any solution else?